# Finding created pthread timer is active or not

Tags: timer, pthreads

I have created many timers in my running application.
At a certain point, I want to check whether a previously created timer is active or not.

pthread_create - creating the timer

timer_settime - starting the timer (recursive timer)

Now somewhere in the application and using the timer id, I will want to check whether that timer is active or not.
Is there an API to do this? If not, How can I do this?

Possible way I was thinking:
-Issue two consecutive timer_gettime() and see if there is any change for the given timer id.
-If there is change, I will consider that as an active timer.

Comment: `man timer_gettime()`: *timer_gettime()  returns  the time until next expiration, and the interval,
       for the timer specified by timerid, in the buffer pointed to by curr_value.
       The  time  remaining  until  the  next  timer  expiration  is  returned  in
       curr_value->it_value; this  is  always  a  relative  value,  regardless  of
       whether  the  TIMER_ABSTIME  flag  was  used when arming the timer.  If the
       value returned in curr_value->it_value is zero, then the timer is currently
       disarmed.*

Comment: @EOF Thanks a lot.